# Can't scroll my site when I open it in the browser [DREAMWEAVER CS6]

Tags: jquery, html, css, dreamweaver

I'm new to web design and am making a static site. Looking to make one with a solid background image which stays in place when the user scrolls (implemented already minus scrolling) and then include some portfolios and slideshows in it (it's based on a photography design).

I have some jquery in place to hold a large background image no matter the user. Also some jquery for a slideshow which is not yet implemented.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
```

AND

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
```

If I haven't given enough info just ask and I can tell you whatever you need!

Edit: Full code of the page -

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style type="text/css">
#fsbg {
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: -100;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 1000px;
}
</style>

<style>

#navigation li {
 font: 34px Ostrich "Ostrich Sans";
 display: inline;
 list-style: none;
 text-shadow: inherit; 
 }
 
#navigation a {
 padding: 25px 35px;
 background-color:;
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: inherit;
}
#navigation a:hover {
 background-color: #FFF;
 color: #CCC;
 



 
}
#maintext {
 font-family: "Ostrich Sans", "Ostrich Sans Rounded";
 font-size: 100px;
 color: #000;
 background-color: #FFF;
 height: 900px;
 width: 700px;
 position: fixed;
 left: 25%;
 top: 20%;
 text-shadow: inherit;
}
</style>
</head>

<body topmargin="60">

<nav>
<div id="navigation">
  <div id="maintext">
    <p>Gallery</p>
    <p><img src="images/alaska.jpg" width="700" height="462" alt="alaska" /></p>
  </div>
  <div id="main_body">
    <h5>&nbsp;</h5>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">photography</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">media</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact me</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<img src="images/1920x1080.jpg" name="fsbg" width="1920" height="1281" id="fsbg" />
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".fancybox").fancybox();
  });

</script>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: can you provide the html?

Comment: Sorry, pretty poorly worded - I know. I have just begun making this site, my first time using any jquery etc. I have a site which has one large background image and when I put a box to include images, text etc. into in the middle of the page it will not let me scroll down to see below what is initially seen upon entering the page. In the following link I cannot see the rest of the image: http://gyazo.com/2d4cdac12af04d0947500bf5e83cf229

Comment: Jason, I will include the whole code I have from my 2nd page (the page with the problem) in the original post now. Thanks.

Comment: i don't see the problem. what's your question? what image? what exactly do you want to do? Plus, you don't have an element to run your fancybox on. see this: http://fancybox.net/howto

Comment: See the image in my post in response to Tim. I have the image on, it's just something along the way has stopped me being able to scroll down when on the webpage. Probably a simple fix, I'm sure. I have made even more basic sites from style sheets and div tags before similar to this - just trying out the large background style. And what I want to do is scroll down so I can see and add more images in a portfolio type setting. Yes, FancyBox is not yet implemented. I just have that bit of code in while I work on this.

Comment: Of course it's not scrolling... you have `position:fixed` on everything inside of `#maintext` and that's what `fixed` means.

Comment: Sparky - thanks. I didn't know that affected it in this way. Just followed numerous tutorials - they must have had some conflicting uses of position. But I've changed that to absolute and now it is working as I intended. Thanks very much, again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can't have `position:fixed` because that destroys scrolling. Second, use auto margins on the left and right to center it.

```
#maintext{
    position: static;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

EDIT: two more things:

1) take out these two lines affecting `#maintext`:

```
left: 25%; 
top: 20%;
```

2) in response to your comment

> When I use static it forces the menu bar at the top of the page to the bottom, absolute fixes this.

Look up the difference between different types of positioning. Here's something I found really quick: http://www.yorku.ca/nmw/facs1939f13/week02/css_relVSabsVSfixed.html I don't want to give you the answer to only this situation, since that wouldn't be constructive, but I will get you started:

When you have fixed, it doesn't affect the rest of the page. When you have static positioning, like my answer above told you to do, it affects the flow. So since the `#maintext` part came first, it will appear first. I hope you know what to do!

Comment: One more quick question. When I use static it forces the menu bar at the top of the page to the bottom, absolute fixes this. However I do not know if that is advised against.

Comment: Oh feel free to ask for direction if you are stuck with your last comment.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body 
            {
            background-image:url('earth.jpg');
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-attachment:fixed;
            }
```

Put the above code in between style tags and place it before the closing of your head tag in html page.

This may solve your problem. Please dont forget to tick the answer correct if it works for you.

Comment: What that has done, Dipali, is put the image in question over the top of the background image and behind the white text box and image. See: http://gyazo.com/566a4613c7a7887040fb074dc857585e

Comment: You want your background image to be fix even if the user scrolls down right ?

Comment: Correct. Here is the tutorial that I used to get that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnWl0RKhjEQ

Comment: Diapli, "Sparky" solved the issue for me in the comments below my question. Thank you very much for your time, though! I'm sure you would have pointed out my mistake shortly.